# Удаление дерева

Tags: c, указатели, дерево, бинарное-дерево

здравствуйте. мне нужно, помимо прочего, написать функцию удаления всего дерева.
я написал функцию *delete_tree*. после функции *free()* для проверки сделал вывод по удаленному указателю и, к удивлению, обнаружил, что все значения выводятся. 
почему так происходит?

```
typedef struct tree 
{
    int value;
    struct tree *l, *r;
} tree;

void delete_tree(tree **cur)
{
    if(*cur != NULL)
    {
        delete_tree(&(*cur)->l);
        delete_tree(&(*cur)->r);
        free(cur);
        printf("%d \n", (*cur)->value);
        *cur = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Освобождение памяти не означает ее обнуление или запись в нее каких-то иных значений, так что сразу после удаления, пока память не выделена для других целей и не перезаписана - она хранит старые значения.
Вот вы с ними и работаете.
Но это - неопределенное поведение...

Comment: об этом я не думал. спасибо, что напомнили. что значит "неопределенное поведение"?

Comment: Значит, что ничего определенного сказать о том, как себя поведет программа при таком использовании освобожденной памяти, невозможно. Может что-то вывести разумное, а может и ерунду, а может и аварийно завершиться из-за нарушения доступа - словом, все, что угодно.

Comment: Да, @VladfromMoscow увидел то, на что не обратил внимание я - но в любом случае, это не отменяет написанное мною.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша функция имеет неопределенное поведение, так как данное предложение

```
free(cur);
```

некорректное.

Вместо него должно быть

```
free( *cur );
     ^^^
```

Поэтому на самом деле функция не удаляет узлы дерева. Тем не менее, если вы исправите данную опечатку, то обращение к памяти после ее освобождения ведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Поэтому данное предложение

```
printf("%d \n", (*cur)->value);
```

также является некорректным.

Comment: усек. в остальном функция нормальна?

Comment: @Halva Это означает, что функция на самом деле не удаляет узлы дерева. Что касается остального, то если вы исправите указанную ошибку, то, тем не менее, обращение к памяти после ее удаления, как это имеет место в предложении printf("%d \n", (*cur)->value);
 ведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: значит, убираю *printf*, изменяю *free* по-Вашему и получаю нормальную функцию удаления всего дерева?

Comment: @Halva Получаете рекурсивную функцию удаления узлов дерева.